# how to display json data in the form of dropdown using java script?

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

Below is my code.
Here i am returning a json data object.

```
def db_dropdown():  # Execute query
    db_path = "C:\sqlite\marketoperation.db"
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''SELECT id,name FROM Generator''')
    row_headers = [x[0] for x in c.description]  # this will extract row headers
    rv = c.fetchall()
    print(rv)
    json_data = []
    for result in rv:
        json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))
    print('executed')
    print(json.dumps(json_data))
    data=json.dumps(json_data)
    return data
```

the 'data' is in the form:
[{"id": 1, "name": "a1"}, {"id": 2, "name": "a2"}]
this is my flask code where i am calling try.html and passing the json data.

```
@app.route('/trying', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index1():
    list_tested = db_dropdown()
    print(list_tested)
    return render_template("try.html", trial1=list_tested)
```

this is my try.html

```
<body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
        <select id="gendropdown" name="gendropdown">
        </select>
        <button type="submit" onclick="clicked()">Submit</button>
    <script>
 var trail1 = {{trail1}}
          var jobj = JSON.parse(trail1);
          let dropdown = document.getElementById('gendropdown');
           dropdown.length = 0;

            let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
            defaultOption.text = 'Choose State/Province';

            dropdown.add(defaultOption);
            dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;
            let option;
    for (let i = 0; i < jobj.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement('option');
      option.text = data[i].name;
        option.value = data[i].id;
        dropdown.add(option);

        </script>
      </body>
```

i tried to post the json data in the form of dropdown. but it is not working.
please suggest the changes. I want to display the json data in the format of drop down.